# Can't compare login info

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am currently creating an extremely simple login system where a file is stored on the client's computer with the login info stored in a file called loginInfo.txt. The file is created and I entered in the correct info when I ran it but the login failed. Here's the code

```py
class UserInfo():
        def login():
            try:
                loginInfo = open('loginInfo.txt', 'r')
                loginInfo_LineByLine = loginInfo.readlines() # create a list of each line in the login info file

                correctUsername = loginInfo_LineByLine[0] # store what the correct username is 
                correctPassword = loginInfo_LineByLine[1] # store what the correct password is

                loginInfo.close() # we don't need anymore data from the login file so we can close it

                inputtedUsername = input('Username: ') # get a usename and password from the user
                inputtedPassword = input('Password: ')

                if(inputtedUsername == correctUsername):
                    # checks if the correct info was entered
                    if(inputtedPassword == correctPassword):
                        # if the correct info was entered then give the user sudo priviledges and get their email info for email sending
                        sudo = True
                        email = input('Email(allow less secure apps must be enabled): ')
                        password = input('Email Password: ')
                        global username
                        username = inputtedUsername
                        print("hi")

                else:
                    # if incorrect info was entered return an error
                    print(inputtedPassword)
                    print(correctPassword)
                    print(inputtedUsername)
                    print(correctUsername)
                    print(inputtedPassword == correctPassword and inputtedUsername == correctUsername)

                    print('Login failed restart Geeko Helpr if you wish to try again otherwise you will not have access to sudo features')
                    global username
                    username = inputtedUsername

            except IOError:
                # alert the user that no login info was found
                print('Your login info doesn\'t seem to exist please create a login')

                loginInfo = open('loginInfo.txt', 'a+') # create the login info file

                loginUsername = input('What would you like to be your username: ') # ask fo a username and password and store them as variables for later
                loginPassword = input('What would you like to use as your password: ')

                loginInfo.write(loginUsername + "\n")
                loginInfo.write(loginPassword)

                loginInfo.close()
                quit()
```

This code is called on startup. I'm not getting any errors but the login is failing. When I print wether or not the correct info was passed in `False` is printed.

Comment: Eeeeeeeehhhhhhhhhh I think you should hesitate before rolling your own authentication system.  If that file is not encrypted, you are putting your client at risk. `print(correctPassword)` - yikes.

Comment: This is just beta code local to my computer I am printing the info so I can check the values. By printing the correct info I can see if I just entered something wrong this will not be included in the official release.